# How to make adjoining closed paths with no overlaps, gaps or slivers in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, vector, shapes

I have a series of closed paths that I want to exactly abut each other with zero gaps, overlaps, or slivers between them. Each path's shape outline should draw exactly on top of each other. In the geospatial world I;m familiar with this is referred to as [topology](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/topology.html) and [there are tools](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/topo_editing.html) to snap or trace lines together so each vertex has identical coordinates. Is there something similar in Inkscape?

Up to this point I've been doing that by snapping nodes to each other, removing nodes in one shape that don't exist in another, and moving the bezier handles to approximate the other shapes. It's very slow though, and any edit in one shape must be repeated in all the others, and sometimes the outlines don't lineup even though they look like they should.

In the absence of GIS-like topology tools, is there perhaps a method of making nodes and bezier handles of non-selected features visible? That would be one way of making manual editing more efficient.

*In this figure I've used Stroke Markers to show the vertices among 3 adjoining polygons (red, blue, & grey).*
[image: stroke settings]
[image: 3 adjoining polygons]

*In this close up of a shared intersection among 3 polygons up we see the nodes are snapped but the line locations differ because the bezier handles aren't matched (handles not shown).*
[image: Nodes are snapped but lines differ]

Comment: Are you trying to create this from scratch or are you trying to edit paths that are already created?  If the former, you can certainly use a Division boolean operation to create something like a map without overlapping paths [see example](https://imgur.com/a/Xvq5usF). The black lines here used for the division boolean operation need to be a combined (or compound) path for this to work.

Comment: @BillyKerr paths are already created, cleaning up from a trace (manually, with a digital pen). Thanks for the division example! I'll definitely use that next time. However even with that beginning (which will save a lot of work) there is still a lot of moving shared boundaries in the work I'm doing.

Comment: I am not sure about Inkscape (Illustrator user) but if you make the top path the perfect shape you want and the underlying paths big enough to overlap under the "perfect" one- then you can use the boolean "trim" function to cut the uppermost path out of the underlying ones. Perfect for fitting together nicely... Inkscape must have a similar function- not to mention the possible conflation artifacts- but that is another question (with many answers here on GDSE.